# Native Camera Using get Rotation

Tags: android, native

I am lot of stuff for finding Camera rotation(Angle -0,90,180,270) after IMAGE_CAPTURE but not getting correct rotation degree. I am using **ExifInterface** class but getting "0" or "1".

```
    //Image Capture 
    final static int CAMERA_OUTPUT = 0; 
    File file;     


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.camerapreview); 
    Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Images/" + image_name + ".jpg");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT); 

    } 



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent); 

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    { 
    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsoultePath());
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
    //In Log getting 0 or 1 issue
   Log.d("tag","Rotation is "+orientation);
    }
    }
```

Please give some idea how to get rotation degree after image capture.

Comment: Well, those are valid values for the attribute. See http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html

Comment: But getting Exif class always return  1 issue , if i am capture Landcape reverse or portrait reverse . I dn't know why this issue arise

Comment: Perhaps the camera app is not setting the EXIF orientation header, but is just saving the image in the proper orientation.

Comment: If i am saving propely in sdcard or default location but at that time "after image capture " OnActivity result how to get orientation(degree- 0,90,180,270)